# How to use UWP context features?

Tags: xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

Specifically I'm talking about UIElement.ContextRequested and UIElement.ContextFlyout. My understanding of this is that the following code:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red">
            <Rectangle.ContextFlyout>
                <MenuFlyout>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Edit"/>
                    <MenuFlyoutItem Text="Delete"/>
                </MenuFlyout>
            </Rectangle.ContextFlyout>
 </Rectangle>
```

Would cause the context menu to show when I right click it on desktop. However, nothing happens. The contextrequested event doesn't seem to fire on desktop either. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you targeting minimum version 14393 for your project?

Comment: Yes. For some reason when I copied all my code into a new project, it worked. Visual studio glitch or something, I guess. My old project still doesn't work with it, so I suspect it may be because it was originally not targeted for 14393 and the retarget feature didn't work with this for some reason.